# In javascript why name a variable equal to a function

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and am told setting a variable equal to a function is done all the time.  I'm trying to figure out why.  Below is sample code that suggests there is no advantage.  What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         var  addVar =  function() {
            var myTemp = 0;

            for(i=0; i< arguments.length;i++){
               myTemp+=arguments[i];
            }
            return myTemp;
         }

         function addFunc() {
            var myTemp = 0;

            for(i=0; i< arguments.length;i++){
               myTemp+=arguments[i];
            }
            return myTemp;
         }

         function addTwo(first,second){
            return first+second;
         }

         alert( addTwo(addVar(1,2,3),addVar(1,2,3)) );
         alert( addTwo(addFunc(1,2,3),addFunc(1,2,3)) );


</script>
```

Comment: In this case, there is no advantage. If you need to change the function dynamically, then you need a variable.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by change function dynamically?  I thought they were immutable

Comment: Let's suppose you have an async function. When it ends, how do you specify what do? With a callback. And how do you explain to the async function what is a "callback"? You simply put a function in a variable and pass it. Advantage: if you have multiple async functions and you want all of them to do the same thing when they end, you don't have to write the callback every time.

Comment: great answer, thanks

Comment: @DCR Maybe later on in the program, you want `addVar` to do something different. You can change the `addVar` variable to hold a different function.